# How to solve EditText recursion issues in android

Tags: android

I have two EditText when i enter input in first EditText  values will also show in second EditText and vice versa.When i entering  in first edittext values is showing in second edittext but when i trying to enter in second edit text value is not showing and Application is not responding.I tried multiple time after adding TextWatcher and Removing from another edit text but unable to solve the issue.Thank You so much for your help.

```
    etuptext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            et_bottom.setText(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    et_bottom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


          //  etuptext.setText(charSequence.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: post stack traces

Comment: I think the solution is to check if the text is actually changed.

Comment: Try appending the text rather that setting it directly.. this may solve your purpose. If want to see values simultaneously in both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use view `hasFocus()` method to check weather the other `EditText` has focus. If not then set text otherwise do nothing.

**Here is the working code:**

```
etuptext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        if (!et_bottom.hasFocus())
            et_bottom.setText(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});

et_bottom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        if (!etuptext.hasFocus())
            etuptext.setText(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to check is you reflecting EditText is should not be focus.

```
 etuptext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
          if(!et_bottom.hasFocus())
            et_bottom.setText(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    et_bottom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

         if(!etuptext.hasFocus())
           etuptext.setText(charSequence.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

One more thing all this happening because when you trying to set text to EditText then it got focus and writing in one and second one will requesting focus so app is getting into Not Responding mode.

Comment: What is the difference between your code and my code? I have already answered this.

Comment: Difference between posts is just explanation at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the TextWatchers before setting the text. After setting the text, add the TextWatcher again.

In pseudo code:

```
TextWatcher edittext1watcher = null;
TextWatcher edittext2watcher = null;

edittext1watcher = new TextWatcher () {
...
    public void onTextChanged(.....) {
        edittext2.removeTextChangedListener(edittext2watcher);
        edittext2.setText(...);
        edittext2.addTextChangedListener(edittext2watcher);
    }
};
edittext2watcher = new TextWatcher () {
...
    public void onTextChanged(.....) {
        edittext1.removeTextChangedListener(edittext1watcher);
        edittext1.setText(...);
        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(edittext1watcher);
    }
};

edittext1.addOnTextChangedListener(edittext1watcher);
edittext2.addOnTextChangedListener(edittext2watcher);
```